# Invalid results file. result format of the file 'C:\vstsAgents\A6\_work\r1\a\TestResults\LODADE-20_09_30_50.trx' matches 'VSTest' results format

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm setting azure pipeline release by selenium webdriver continous integration.  I have added `"Visual studio test platform installer"` and `"vstest- TestAssemblies"` in release to get test result. But I'm getting this warning while `"VStest-TestAsseblies run".`

and after succesfull deployment  I get this result in Test Tab

> "No test runs are available for this build. Run tests and get rich
>   reports by using an appropriate built-in task such as the Visual
>   Studio Test task. Alternately, run tests using a runner of your choice
>   such as JUnit, xUnit, mocha, jest, pytest, rspec, etc. and use the
>   Publish Test Results task to get rich reports."

Even I have one test case which work fine on visual code locally.