# Invalid results file. ] result format of 'C:\Agents\Build\Agent1\_work\45\s\TestResults24_59.trx' matches 'VSTest' test results format

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

I have a unit test written in visual studio with login flow. And It runs perfectly when running locally. But when I push the code in Azure repo and create a new build in azure pipeline. In "VSTest" I face this warning

> "Invalid results file. Make sure the result format of the file
>   'C:\Agents\Build\Agent1_work\45\s\TestResults\MS$_MS_2019-04-21_12_24_59.trx'
>   matches 'VSTest' test results format."

And after creation of build no test is available in Tests tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid results file. result format of the file 'C:\vstsAgents\A6\‌\_work\r1\a\TestResults\LODADE-20\_09\_30\_50.trx' matches 'VSTest' results format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782939/invalid-results-file-result-format-of-the-file-c-vstsagents-a6-work-r1-a-tes)

Comment: Please **do not** repost the same question. If your existing question isn't getting enough attention, update it and add more details.